# Getting a Field from an instance?

Tags: java

Is there any way to get a Field reference from an instance (not from a class) ?

This is an example :

```
public class Element {
    @MyAnnotation("hello")
    public String label1;

    @MyAnnotation("world")
    public String label2;
}

public class App {
    private Element elem = new Element();

    public void printAnnotations() {
        String elemLabel1 = elem1.label;
        String elemLabel2 = elem2.label;

    // cannot do elemLabel.getField().getDeclaredAnnotations();
        String elemLabel1AnnotationValue = // how ? 
        String elemLabel2AnnotationValue = // how ? 
    }
}
```

---

Sorry for not being too clear, but i already know how to fetch Fields from a class (Class --> Field --> DeclaredAnnotations)

What i am wondering is how to get the Field for a particular instance.
In this example, from elemLabel1 string instance, i wish to be able to get the Field of Element.label1.

Comment: To me it seems like you're asking something different in your sample from your title.  Are you trying to get the annotation or the field?

Comment: It's actually getting the field first before being able to get the annotation on that particular field, hence it's about the getting the field in my opinion.

Comment: From the way the question is phrased, it sounds like you already know how to get data from a class, but you want to get information from an instance.  If so, `.getClass()` might work for you.

Comment: Yes, but imagine what i have is only the String instance (maybe passed as a method parameter). I dont know the Class that contains the String instance, so i cannot do Element.class.getField("label1").getDeclaredAnnotations().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean? A `Field` on defined on the `Class`. You can get the *value* for a specific instance:-

```
private static class Test {
    private int test = 10;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Test test = new Test();
    final Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("test");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    final int value = field.getInt(test);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

The the `class Test` has a `Field` called `test`. This is true of any `Test` - it is defined in the `Class`. The instance of the `class` is has a specific value for that `Field`, in this case `10`. This can retrieved for a specific instance using the `getXXX` or `get` method.

**EDIT**

From the code in your question it looks like you want the value of an `Annotation` field not the value of a `class` field.

In Java, values in annotations are compile time constants and therefore are also defined at the `class` rather than instance level.

```
public class Element {
    @MyAnnotation("l")
    public String label;
}
```

In your example, the `MyAnnotation` value field must be equal to `1` for *every* instance of `Element`.

Comment: So that I can reference it from the `static void main` method when its defined in the same `class` file . Just to make the example more succinct.

Comment: Hello Boris. Yes, it's class level definition. But in my program, i cannot know the Class that contains the annotated String. What i have is only the String instance (maybe passed as a method parameter). And i was wondering whether i can get the Field of that String instance only.

Comment: Unless you know the field name, no.

Answer (score 2):

`Field` belongs to class. Therefore you actually want to do the following:

`elemLabel.getClass().getField("theFieldName").getDeclaredAnnotations();`

However although your field is `public` typically all fields should be `private`. In this case use `getDeclaredField()` instead of `getField()`.

EDIT
you have to call `field.setAccessible(true)` before using the field.

Comment: Thanks for the notes that Field belongs to the Class. But in my case, a String is just a string, because the program may not know what Class that contains that String. So i was wondering whether i can get the Field for the String instance.